# Is it true that everything that isn't linear is concave or convex (or both)?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, economics

In the conclusion of *anti-fragile* by Taleb, he claims that "everything non-linear is concave or convex, or both".

Is the statement general, and if not, what are its limitations?
I suppose he is talking about continuous functions, although he doesn't mention it.
If yes, can you provide a proof for the statement - or at least a convincing sketch.

**EDIT (3)**: we established that the statement is false in *general*. It seems that by " both concave and convex", Taleb means that the function is alternatively concave or convex on disjoints sub-domains, like the sinus function - so it still wouldn't be linear (otherwise his statement is obviously void).

So let's assume we have a continuous nonlinear function over a bounded real-valued domain; is there a decomposition of the domain such that every sub-domain, arbitrarily small, is either concave or convex? Or is there a function which doesn't have this property?

Comment: Of course it is grossly false. That pseudo-scientist has a tendency for exaggeration.

Comment: For first, concave+convex *implies* linear, so just the "both" part of the first line is clearly wrong. Second: convexity or concavity imply continuity on the interior of the domain, but not every function is continuous.

Comment: it becomes true if you change it just a bit: everything non-linear is concave, or ocnvex, or both, or neither.

Comment: You will have to restrict that statement to have the slightest chance of being true. Take the $\sin$ function for example...

Comment: Then take the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function), and cry.

Comment: the problem (after the edit) has a trivial solution: You can always decompose the domain into a system of singleton and a function on singleton is, well, constant. you should at least require the subdomains to be intervals of positive length. And I think you have countably many subdomains in mind.

Comment: @user251257 Yes. I'll add this requirement.

Comment: @Symeof oh sorry, I see it just now. That won't be true in general: Think about $f''(x) = x \sin(x^{-1})$. you need to allow singleton intervals ...

Comment: Edited back to what it was before.

Comment: I meant you should require countably many intervals. as for uncountably many it is trivially true.

Comment: I would guess the Weierstrass function is a counterexample to the most recent version.  IMO it's better to give up hope that this kind of statement could be true in anything but the most trivial cases.

Comment: @AntonioVargas are you referring to the case with countably or uncountably many intervals?

Comment: Countably.$ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: oh yes: convex functions on open intervals are almost everywhere differentiable. there are many nowhere differentiable but continuous functions, like the Weierstrass function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is basically given in the comments. I write them up just to give the question some closure.

It makes only sense to speak about convexity / concavity of a real function $f$ if the domain is an interval. So the question is, is there a system $\mathscr I$ of intervals such that $f$ restricted on each interval in $\mathscr I$ is either convex or concave.

If we allow $\mathscr I$ to be uncountable, we can select the intervals as singletons and the statement is trivially true.

If we require $\mathscr I$ to be countable, then there exists at least one $I\in \mathscr I$ with positive length. Now, a convex or concave function on an open interval is locally Lipschitz continuous and thus almost everywhere differentiable. So $f$ needs to be almost everywhere differentiable on the interior of $I$. However, there are nowhere differentiable yet continuous functions like the Weierstrass function. So the statement is in general wrong. (Aside the set of nowhere differentiable, continuous functions is dense).

If we additionally require that $f$ is differentiable, then $f'$ needs to be monotone and thus again almost everywhere differentiable on any open interval on which $f$ is convex or concave. So we should at least require twice differentiability. It reduces to following statement / claim (think $g=f''$):

> Let $g:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$  have the intermediate value property. Then, there exists a countable system of intervals $\mathscr I$ such that  $g$ restricted on each $I\in\mathscr I$ is either completely non-negative or completely non-positive.

However, I have no idea whether it is true or not....

Comment: True if implied that it is continuous and differential in every sub-interval.

Comment: @Narasimham you are speaking about $g$, aren't you? that's much stronger than just the intermediate value property

Comment: Yes, so that sub-interval curvature is unaffected.

Comment: @Narasimham hm could you explain your idea? I can't see it